# How would someone premine a direct fork of monero ( can it be done )

Tags: monerod, genesisblock

I am wondering if it is possible to 100% premine a fork of monero.

I also want to set the block reward to 0.

I have looked at cryptonote genesis block creation notes around the web, but I do not know if this would be the same as premining. I also do not know if it applied to monero anymore.

I have successfully compiled many crypto's but I am starting to realize that there is much more to learn about them!

Comment: To give a little more prospective. 

I want to use the blockchain in a different way.. More like an asset or private security. At the same time I want it to be as open as possible.

As I like monero I wanted to use that as my base. 

The goal is to build something more open than gold money, with the monero privacy and security features. But because each unit will have a physical value, I can not let this be mined in the traditional way. This should also allow the security to be traded on crypto exchanges like a currency unlike gold money ( bitgold ).

Answer (score 3):

It should be easy to emit all the coins in the first block:

Look for `get_block_reward` in cryptonote_basic_impl.cpp. You see how you're given the number of already generated coins. For the first block, it will be zero. In that case, you can return a large amount. For the second block, that value will be equal to the first block's reward. You can then return 0 if the number of already generated coins is not 0.

Note that there might be other bits and bobs needing some updating, mostly in tests.

Comment: line 92 of src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic_impl.h

bool get_block_reward(size_t median_size, size_t current_block_size, uint64_t already_generated_coins, uint64_t &reward, uint8_t version);

Lets assume I have a maximum supply of 5000000 coins of which 90% are premined. Where do I modify the Monero code to show this? Also, where do I specify the wallet address for the pre-mined coins to be sent to? I have created a separate question for this now https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8717/pre-mined-monero-fork

Answer (score 1):

Monero has a tail emission, so it will never be 100% mined.  You could probably take it apart and put it back together with a hard cap, but that would entail more than changing a few config variables.

Comment: He could do a pre-mine by just tweaking the emission. Like give 100% of the planned emission in the first block, and kill-off the tail emission. No idea how to actually do this, though.

Comment: https://github.com/Ninespire/Ravecoin-cryptonote <-- would the config files from this work on Monero?

Is monero different than cryptonote? Like would there be any advantage to forking monero over cryptonote for my requirements?

Comment: @CryptoNote is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

The premine can be done for any crypto note coin.

In the configuration file.

You will set 2 areas.
One will be the premine amount in percentage.

The other variable to set is the wallet address that it will be sent to from the premine ,that will be conducted on first run.

The cryptonote ,called forknote has a premine function and when it is set bails out on the webpage with an error.

But from what I remember.

Yes you can setup a premine
And make it go directly into a wallet for ico or funding startup purposes.

Good luck :-)