# Pre-Mined Monero Fork

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mining, cryptonote, monero-forks

I would like to create a Fork of Monero with a certain number of coins premined.

I have tried to follow [How would someone premine a direct fork of monero ( can it be done )](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3574/how-would-someone-premine-a-direct-fork-of-monero-can-it-be-done) but it is incomplete.

Based on this, I have found on line 92 of *src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic_impl.h*

> bool get_block_reward(size_t median_size, size_t current_block_size,
>   uint64_t already_generated_coins, uint64_t &reward, uint8_t version);

Lets assume I have a maximum supply of 5000000 coins of which 90% are premined. Where do I modify the Monero code to show this? Also, where do I specify the wallet address for the pre-mined coins to be sent to?

Comment: Why do you want / need to premine?

Comment: i inserted on cryptonote_basic_impl.h but didnt work. maybe is need to be inserted on cpp? i must remove (size_t median_size, size_t current_block_size, uint64_t already_generated_coins, uint64_t &reward, uint8_t version);

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line of code in the first line of the `get_block_reward` function for premine, set  the reward of your choice

```
 if(already_generated_coins == 0) {
       reward = 4000000;
       return true;
    }
```